# How to import a batch of SWRL rules into an OWL ontology without manually importing them one by one?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, swrl

I am currently working on creating Ontology (OWL) files for my project, and I need to specify a large set of SWRL rules (more than 100).

In my current understanding, importing these rules one by one is the only way to do it in the Protege program. However, I am wondering if there is a method to import a batch of SWRL rules into my ontology, bypassing the need to import each rule individually.

I am open to using other programs besides Protege, as long as they offer the functionality to import SWRL rules in bulk.

Comment: isn't Protege itself sufficient? `Refactor -> Merge Ontologies` might be one way to solve your task if your used to Protege? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the [ROBOT](https://robot.obolibrary.org/) command line tool using the [merge](https://robot.obolibrary.org/merge) operation. For example:

```bash
robot merge -i my-ontology.owl -i my-rules.swrl -o combined.owl
```

The `.owl` and `.swrl` files can be any OWL syntax that supports SWRL.